# How to move all files in a folder to s3, and delete local files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-s3

and I think I can use

```
aws s3 sync . s3://s3bucket
```

But I'm not sure where to put the `--delete`

Also I want to run this command from time to time to push all new files in my local folders to s3 and deleting locally. I have few hundred thousand files to move almost ~400,000, how long will it take, each file is ~ 30kb-40kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--delete` option does not do what you think it does. From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

> `--delete` (boolean) Files that exist in the destination but not in the source are deleted during sync.

The [`mv`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html) option may be what you're looking for.

With regards to how long it will take, there's no way anyone but yourself can answer that question.

Comment: thanks @EEAA i did read the documentation and i was confused where to put the delete since i didn't want to do a sync exactly. I missed the mv command, which is exactly what I need. Thanks!